# Swift Don't work auto heigh in custom cell

Tags: swift, cell

Just custom class for cell

```
class CarCell: UITableViewCell { 

override func layoutSubviews() {

    MainImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: spacing * 5).isActive = true
    MainImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
    MainImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -spacing * 5 ).isActive = true
    MainImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -spacing).isActive = true
    MainImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: MainImageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

don't work 2 bottom lines.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(CarCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CarCell")
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
}
```

[image]

I can create this non programmatic  and  I need this result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution!!! when add constraints need to: use self.contentView

MainImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: `self.leftAnchor`, constant: spacing * 5).isActive = true

just change to

MainImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: `self.contentView .leftAnchor`, constant: spacing * 5).isActive = true

Answer (score 0):

You need to add constraints in the cell:

Bottom, top, left, right
and Height(you can you greaterthan >= or lessthan <=)

Also add `clipToBounds = true` for `image view`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try out the following code i think you are missing this

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(CarCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CarCell")
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.datasource = self
}
```

Comment: after this implement heightForRowAtIndexPath method and return height you want.